# WIder cell in XSSFSheet cell?,alignment not working

Tags: xssfsheet

```
 INT_B_BORDERTOP_EUR.setWrapText(false);
    INT_B_BORDERTOP_EUR.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.LEFT);
    XSSFFont fontEur = wb.createFont();[![Example][1]][1]
```

Alignment is not working, merge with another cell not helping. I just want to see numbers and currency EUR.

[image: example]